# Can't add JavaFX lights to multiple SubScenes

Tags: javafx, 3d, javafx-8, javafx-3d

### Problem

In JavaFX is a default light on every 3D Scene. It's a PointLight shining from top of Scene.

I've tried to show in my program the different possibilities of light, but I ran in trouble. If I only add a SubScene with default, PointLight and AmbientLight, everything works as aspected. But if I then add one more SubScene with a combined Light of Ambient and Point, I'll get the result showing in Screenshot 2. It seems all other SubScene lost their light and fall back to it's default light. Maybe I hit a bug?

### Systems tested

- OS: Windows 8.1 x64, Windows 7 x64
- Graphics: AMD 4200 HD, Intel HD 3000
- Java: 1.8.0_45 JDK/JRE x86 (32-Bit), 1.8.0_60ea x64

### Stage with 3 SubScenes - Default, Point, Ambient

[image: 3Lights]

### Stage with 4 SubScenes - Default, Point, Ambient, (Point,Ambient)

[image: 4Lights]

### Example

Here is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Shapes3DViewer extends Application {

  PhongMaterial material;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    material = new PhongMaterial();
    material.setDiffuseColor(Color.FIREBRICK);
    material.setSpecularColor(Color.YELLOW);

    PointLight pointLight = new PointLight(Color.WHITE);
    pointLight.setTranslateX(100);
    pointLight.setTranslateY(100);
    pointLight.setTranslateZ(-300);
    pointLight.setRotate(90);

    AmbientLight ambient = new AmbientLight();

    Group g1 = createSphereGroup(100, "Default light");
    Group g2 = createSphereGroup(100, "Point light");
    Group g3 = createSphereGroup(100, "Ambient light");
    Group g4 = createSphereGroup(100, "Ambient & Point light");

    g2.getChildren().add(pointLight);
    g3.getChildren().add(ambient);
    g4.getChildren().addAll(pointLight, ambient);

    SubScene s1 = createSubScene(g1, 400, 400);
    SubScene s2 = createSubScene(g2, 400, 400);
    SubScene s3 = createSubScene(g3, 400, 400);
    SubScene s4 = createSubScene(g4, 400, 400);

    HBox root = new HBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll(s1, s2, s3, s4);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  private Group createSphereGroup(double radius, String text) {
    Sphere c = new Sphere(radius);
    c.setMaterial(material);
    c.setDrawMode(DrawMode.FILL);
    c.setTranslateX(radius * 1.33);
    c.setTranslateY(radius * 2);
    Label lbl = new Label(text);
    lbl.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;-fx-font-size: 18pt;");
    return new Group(c, lbl);
  }

  private SubScene createSubScene(Group group, double width, double height) {
    SubScene s = new SubScene(group, width, height);
    s.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera());
    s.setFill(Color.color(.1, .1, .1));
    return s;
  }
}
```

*Output of MCVE on:*

```
javafx.runtime.version=8.0.45-b11
OS X 10.9.5
2014 Macbook Pro
```

[image: mac test]

### Question

Am I doing wrong, or is this a bug? Can someone confirm the same behaviour?

### Update

I've made a new test where I added two new lights: pointLight2 and ambient2. 
That both I've added to the fourth sphere. This solution works.

```
PointLight pointLight2 = new PointLight(Color.WHITE);
    pointLight.setTranslateX(100);
    pointLight.setTranslateY(100);
    pointLight.setTranslateZ(-300);
    pointLight.setRotate(90);

AmbientLight ambient2 = new AmbientLight();

g4.getChildren().addAll(pointLight2, ambient2);
```

[image: 4Lights-new]

It seems that the lights will be merged and only added to one Scene and removed from all other scenes.

### Conclusion

As jewselsea explained in his answer, this is **not a bug**! But from my point of view they should repeat that statement in the Light Classes again or make a hint, because it's a little bit confusing.

[SubScene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SubScene.html) needs a [Parent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html) as root in his constructor, so you don't have a choice.

Comment: What system and which Java version are you using? On my Mac with JDK 8u60 ea the result looks a bit different. The reflection of the point light is not in the middle as in your case. Instead it looks like the point light example in your upper example.

Comment: @mipa I've updated my question. I've tested it with two different systems (PC/Notebook) both Windows systems. Can't see any other result on different systems.

Comment: I edited the question to add a screenshot of what I get on a Mac when I run the mcve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug.  A [PointLight](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/PointLight.html) is a [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html).  Node javadoc states: "If a program adds a child node to a Parent (including Group, Region, etc) and that node is already a child of a different Parent or the root of a Scene, the node is automatically (and silently) removed from its former parent."  So the application appears to be behaving as expected.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I haven't looked up at super classes.